# How to get root elements contains specific character

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json file and want to extract all root elements contains a specific character in array.

My json file structure:

```
{
"12": [
    "12",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {}\r\n}"
],
"19": [
    "23",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019***091\",\r\n    \"2\": \"2019****67\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
"20": [
    "434",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019****83\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
"333": [
    "25",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019****32\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
"3454": [
    "55",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019****1\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
"23": [
    "66",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019****5\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
"23424": [
    "34",
    "200 OK",
    "{\r\n  \"ResponseText\": null,\r\n  \"RegistrationUserID\": {\r\n    \"1\": \"2019****2\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
],
```

}

I want to extract all root values contains "***" on them.

Result should looks:

> 19 20 333 3454 23 23424

How can I parse my json file using JQ to extract target root elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@peak's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539910/2158479) is the right answer to the question asked. However, if you want to *dive into* the encoded JSON contained within the top arrays' third elements and search just in them instead, use the `fromjson` builtin:

```
to_entries[]
| select(any(.value[2] | fromjson | .RegistrationUserID[]; test("\\*\\*\\*")))
| .key
```

```
19
20
333
3454
23
23424
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bbwIHfsnGu)

Answer (score 1):

When the extraneous comma is removed from the JSON, and when the -r command-line option is used, the filter:

```
to_entries[]
| select( any(.value[]; test("\\*\\*\\*") ))
| .key
```

produces the stream:

```
19
20
333
3454
23
23424
```

You can easily package these values any way you want, e.g. using jq itself.